# If filename includes spaces how can we download with URLConnection in android?

Tags: java, android

```
try {
    int count;
    URL url = new URL("http://www.exampleserver.com/file names.txt");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SOCKET);
    connection.setRequestProperty("connection", "close");
    connection.connect();
    int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
    long total = 0;
    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(BasindaOneCikanDosyalar);
    byte data[] = new byte[40096];
    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm using this algorithm but if the filename contains a space, I got **java.io.FileNotFoundException**  and **getResponseCode:400**.

Is there library or different algorithm for download URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode your filename part of the URL:

```
String encodedFilename = URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");
URL url = new URL("http://www.exampleserver.com/" + encodedFilename);
```

Comment: i tried it works thanks to you, i can continue my work

Comment: This is not correct. Despite its name, `URLEncoder` is for encoding argument names and values, not URLs, as you can tell from the post-adjustment for `%20` here. The correct technique is given in @PeterPeiGuo's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the url, and make it like the following:

```
http://www.exampleserver.com/file%20names.txt
```

In your code do something like this:

```
URI uri = new URI("http", "www.exampleserver.com", "/file names.txt", null);
URL url = uri.toURL();
```

Comment: You mean when i see space , convert to "%20" ?

Comment: Yes, but there are more rules than that, so the best is to use the code I had above, which does that for you - I updated the answer.